# CUDA cub::DeviceScan and the temp_storage_bytes parameter

Tags: cuda, cub

I'm using `cub::DeviceScan` functiona and the [sample code snippet](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_scan.html#aca0d91db140b65d6693dc9eaed6478de) has a parameter `temp_storage_bytes`, which it uses to allocate memory (which, incidentally, the code snippet never frees).

The code snippet calls `cub::DeviceScan` functions with a pointer to `NULL` memory which triggers it to calculate the required amount of temporary device memory needed for the function, and then returns. The necessary temporary memory is allocated with `cudaMalloc`, and the function call is repeated pointing to this memory. The temporary memory is then freed with `cudaFree` (or probably should be).

I'm doing many repetitions of the device scan on different float arrays, but each float array is identical length.

My question is, can I assume that `temp_storage_bytes` will always be the same value? If so, I can then do a single `cudaMalloc` and a single `cudaFree` for many function calls.

The example is unclear on how the required memory is determined and whether it can change for a given array of a given length.

Comment: I would say yes. Otherwise this would mean that `temp_storage_bytes` depends on the array element values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assume you need only one call to `cub::DeviceScan::InclusiveScan` to determine the amount of temporary `temp_storage_bytes` bytes required if you have repeated calls to `cub::DeviceScan::InclusiveScan` over different arrays of same length. In the example below, I'm calling several times `cub::DeviceScan::InclusiveScan` over different arrays of same length and using only one call to `cub::DeviceScan::InclusiveScan` to determine the amount of temporary size-

```
// Ensure printing of CUDA runtime errors to console
#define CUB_STDERR

#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm> // std::generate

#include <cub/cub.cuh>   // or equivalently <cub/device/device_scan.cuh>
#include <thrust\device_vector.h>
#include <thrust\host_vector.h>

void main(void)
{

    // Declare, allocate, and initialize device pointers for input and output
    int  num_items = 7;

    thrust::device_vector<int> d_in(num_items);
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_out(num_items);

    // Determine temporary device storage requirements for inclusive prefix sum
    void     *d_temp_storage = NULL;
    size_t   temp_storage_bytes = 0;

    cub::DeviceScan::InclusiveSum(d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes, d_in.data(), d_out.data(), num_items);

    // Allocate temporary storage for inclusive prefix sum
    cudaMalloc(&d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes);

    for (int k=0; k<10; k++) {

        thrust::host_vector<int> h_in(num_items);

        thrust::host_vector<int> h_out(num_items,0);

        std::generate(h_in.begin(), h_in.end(), rand);
        d_in = h_in;

         // Run inclusive prefix sum
         cub::DeviceScan::InclusiveSum(d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes, d_in.data(), d_out.data(), num_items);

         int difference = 0;
         int prev = 0;
         for (int i=0; i<num_items; i++) {
              h_out[i] = prev + h_in[i];
              prev = h_out[i];
              int val = d_out[i];
              printf("%i %i %i %i\n",i,difference,h_out[i],d_out[i]);
              difference = difference + abs(h_out[i] - d_out[i]);
         }

         if (difference == 0) printf("Test passed!\n");
         else printf("A problem occurred!\n");

         h_in.shrink_to_fit();
         h_out.shrink_to_fit();

    }

    getchar();

}
```

Comment: Why are you freeing d_temp_storage every iteration of the loop?